# Packing an int into a bitfield in C++

Tags: c++, bit-fields, cpuid

I'm converting some code from ASM to C++, the ASM simply looks like so:

```
mov dword ptr miscStruct, eax
```

the Struct looks like:

```
struct miscStruct_s {
  uLong brandID     : 8,
  chunks            : 8,
  //etc
} miscStruct;
```

Is there an easy one-two line way to fill the struct in C++?
So far I am using:

```
miscStruct.brandID = Info[0] & 0xff; //Info[0] has the same data as eax in the ASM sample.
miscStruct.chunks = ((Info[0] >> 8) & 0xff);
```

That works fine and all, but I have to fill some 9-10 of these bitfield structs, some of them have 30 odd fields. So doing it this way ends up turning 10 lines of code into 100+ which obviously is not so great.

So is there a simple, clean way of replicating the ASM in C++?

I of course tried "miscStruct = CPUInfo[0];" but C++ doesn't like that unfortunately. :(

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int'
```

**..And I can't edit the struct**.

Comment: I ended up using:
`*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&miscStruct) = Info[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation of the assembler instruction is this:

```
miscStruct=*(miscStruct_s *)&Info[0];
```

The casts are needed because C++ is a type-safe language, whereas assembler isn't, but the copying semantics are identical.

Comment: I ended up doing it backwards based on your example.

*reinterpret_cast<int*>(&miscStruct) = Info[0];

It's a little funky but it seems to do the job.

Comment: @Riley, whatever works, the main difference between the two is which side you consider the "real" length. Personally I'd choose the in-memory object (`miscStruct`) to be the real length so you can never overwrite it, whereas in your example, if you later change `miscStruct` to have only one char, you'll corrupt your memory.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy (&miscStruct, &CPUInfo[0], sizeof (struct miscStruct_s));`

should help.

or simply

```
int *temp = &miscStruct;
*temp = CPUInfo[0];
```

Here i have assumed that the type of `CPUInfo` is `int`  . You need to adjust the `temp` pointer type with the datatype of the `CPUInfo` array. Simply typecast the memory address for the structure to the type of the array and assign the value into there using the pointer.

Comment: memcpy (&miscStruct, , &CPUInfo[0], sizeof(miscStruct));